DataSource vs DataContext no DataGridView do Windows Forms
Desde o .NET 7, a Microsoft melhorou os recursos de vinculação (binding) do Windows Forms para aproximá-lo do WPF e de outras tecnologias XAML: Using Command Binding in Windows Forms apps to go Cross-Platform - .NET Blog
Então, entre outras coisas, foi incluída a propriedade DataContext nos controles Windows Forms (Control.DataContext Property), similar ao WPF (FrameworkElement.DataContext Property).
Entretanto, em controles como o DataGridView, que possuía a propriedade DataSource (DataGridView.DataSource Property), as duas propriedades passaram a coexistir.
Mas, qual seria a diferença entre as duas?
